# Can not connect to sql server using laravel in windows

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, pdo

I want to use sql server 2017 in laravel 5.7 but I have trouble to connect DB.

the point is I can cannect with simple dbo string like below

```
try {
$conn = new PDO ("sqlsrv:Server=DESKTOP-PVSDJ8C;Database=Library", "Nazanin", "12569", [])
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Error connecting to SQL Server: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

but when I use laravel to connect

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException could not find driver (SQL:
>   select * from [book])

I double check for php extensions and every thing is ok.

Laravel .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=DESKTOP-PVSDJ8C
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=Library
DB_USERNAME=Nazanin
DB_PASSWORD=12569
```

Comment: have you installed sqlsrv extension?

Answer (score 0):

Change the default driver in in config->database.php from mysql to

```
 'default' => 'sqlsrv',
```

If the bug is not resolved, try the second solution

run

```
php --version
```

and then install the sybase version,ensure that it matches up with the version that your VM uses:

```
sudo apt-get install freetds-common freetds-bin unixodbc php7.#-sybase
```

Hope to help you.